# Iterating through a TimeSpan and running an action every month (or arbitrary unit of time)

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I'm writing a search program that includes a date range- DateFrom and DateTo, both of which are DateTimes. Searching January - April for any search criteria will return the results of January + February + March + April.

I would like to add functionality whereby a user can choose to search each month within a - range, so searching January - April will return each individual month's results. However I'm having trouble finding an intelligent way to implement this for any unit of time larger than days.

So far I'm getting a TimeSpan using:

```
TimeSpan ts = query.DateTo - query.DateFrom;
```

In a perfect world I'd just be able to do something like `foreach (month m in TimeSpan){dostuff}`, however TimeSpan stores dates as integers and does not include any units larger than days. Additionally, I thought maybe I could just use `n = DateFrom.month - DateTo.month` to get the difference in months and run a function in a for loop starting with DateFrom and lasting n months, but this won't work between years.

The last case is definitely fixable but includes a number of tedious special cases. Is there a cleaner / more elegant way of accomplishing this sort of iteration that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for the basic pattern we can use a fairly simple `for` loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> Months(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    for (DateTime date = start; date < end; date = date.AddMonths(1))
        yield return date;
}
```

Now in this case we have a start date that is inclusive and an end date that is exclusive.  If we want to make the end date inclusive, as you have described, we can add:

```
end = end.AddMonths(1);
```

to the start of the method.

Next you have a few other considerations.  Are the datetime objects passed in going to always be the first of the month?  If not, how do you want to support it?  If the start date is Feb 10th do you want the first yielded date to be Feb 1st (the start of the start date's month), March 1st (the first "first day of the month" on or after the start date), or Feb 10th (meaning that each date in the timespan would be the 10th day of that month)?

Those same questions also apply to the end date; do you want the last "first day of the month" before the end date, the first day of the next month, etc.

Also, what should happen if the start date is after the end date?  Should it yield the dates "backwards", should it just pretend the start date is the end date and the end date is the start date?  Should it keep adding days until you've overflowed `DateTime` and come back around to that date?

Pretty much all of these issues aren't too hard to deal with, the hard part is just knowing what you want to do in each case.

Comment: +1! You saved me some typing! `yield return` is the nuts. I'd look into doing this as an extension method on `DateTime` (if that's allowed on a struct, can't recall) like `(new DateTime(...)).To(new DateTime(...))`, and I'd want to parameterize the interval as well.

Comment: @EdPlunkett You can indeed add extension methods to structs, yes, although note that a timespan wouldn't help with adding months like this.  It's fine for adding days, hours, minutes, etc., but a month is not a fixed length of time, so it really does need a special method.  Years are also an issue due to leap years.

Comment: Right, I wasn't thinking when I said TimeSpan.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var months = ((query.DateTo.Year - query.DateFrom.Year) * 12) + query.DateTo.Month - query.DateFrom.Month
for(int i=0;i<months;i++){
   //do stuff as below
   var currentDate=query.DateFrom.AddMonths(i);
}
```